# How to create template protocol for presenter UITableViewCell delegate IN VIPER

Tags: swift, uitableview, protocols, presenter, viper-architecture

I am using VIPER architecture with Swift.
I want to use protocol for presenter to get UITableView delegate, because I do not want to repeat the declarations of those methods for all presenters.

So I have created protocol

```
protocol TableViewPresenterProtocol: class {
    associatedtype Data
    func numberOfSections()-> Int
    func haeaderTitle(secton: Int)-> String?
    func numberOfRows(section: Int)-> Int
    func itemForCell(at indexPath: IndexPath)-> Data
    func didSelect(at indexPath: IndexPath)
}

//for make optional
extension TableViewPresenterProtocol {
    func numberOfSections()-> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func haeaderTitle(secton: Int)-> String? {
        return nil
    }
}

class PaymentViewController {
    var presenter: (PaymentPresenterProtocol & TableViewPresenterProtocol)?
}
```

but XCode shows error

> Protocol 'TableViewPresenterProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Where in the source code do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

In your `PaymentViewController` currently the compiler has no chance to identify what your `associatedtype` `Data` refers to. It can be a `String`, it can be an `Int` or anything else. Swift does not like that. It can't work with that because it is ambiguous what the `associatedtype` really refers to.

In order to solve the issue, we can use `TableViewPresenterProtocol` as a generic constraint to tell Swift actually what type we are referring to. In your case it looks like this:

```
class PaymentViewController<A: TableViewPresenterProtocol> {
    var presenter: (A)?
}
```

And let's say you create a class, which conforms to `TableViewPresenterProtocol`:

```
class SomeOtherController: TableViewPresenterProtocol {
     typealias Data = String
     // Other conformance stuff here
}
```

And now you can say:

```
PaymentViewController<SomeOtherController>()
```

And it will be clear to Swift that the presenter's `associatedtype` `Data` is a `String`.